# creating pg_partman parent table generates error `invalid input syntax for type bigint: "monthly"`

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, pg-partman

I'm trying to use pg_partman extension for the first time but cannot create the parent table. This is my command:

```sql
SELECT partman.create_parent('public.mytable_by_date','start_time','native','monthly');
```

That generates this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "monthly"
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function partman.create_parent(text,text,text,text,text[],integer,text,text,boolean,text,text,text[],boolean,text,boolean,text) line 551 at assignment
DETAIL: 
HINT: 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function partman.create_parent(text,text,text,text,text[],integer,text,text,boolean,text,text,text[],boolean,text,boolean,text) line 788 at RAISE
```

I tried `daily` and `quarterly` too but they return same error.

pg_partman: 4.6.0
Postgres:12.9
Ubuntu: 20.04.01

Answer (score 0):

I found out the Problem.
The `start_time` column type is integer and data is stored using unix timestamp but as number and `monthly` only works with data columns.
I have to convert `start_time` column to timestamp first.